# What's the solution for adding unique slug to prevent duplicate entry in creating?

Tags: laravel

i'm working on a project for my homework which i'm trying to make it work as a spa, but I've got some problem in making slug for posts.

in the tutorial which i've followed, instructor used this to make a slug from title :

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::creating(function ($course){
        $course->slug = str_slug($course->name);
    });
}
```

now, if i make this table unique, which this is what i wanna do. how should i prevent app from giving me duplicate entry? or how can i add something to slug, like a number, Every time i get duplicate entry?

if i make a post with `This Post` name twice, second time, i get duplicate Error.

Comment: You can append time in the slug it will never be same, like:
`$course->slug = str_slug( $course->name . time() );`

Comment: If slug exists, append/increment a counter at end of slug. e.g. `my_slug_1`

Comment: @levi can u give me an example base on what i've said? how u check slug exist in this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion your selected answer is not getting close to something efficient. In large applications the 2 random strings can be overwritten in a short time and then you will have huge issues (code and DB).

A safer approach is to build a service and use that when you save the slug in the DB. Or course this is not 100% perfect but definitely is better then to increment 2 random strings. That, by the way, can also affect the SEO part of the app.
Below you can find my example:

**The Model**

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::saving(function ($model) {
        $slug = new Slug();
        $model->slug = $slug->createSlug($model->title);
    });
}
```

**The Service**

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use App\Job;

class Slug
{
    /**
     * @param $title
     * @param int $id
     * @return string
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function createSlug($title, $id = 0)
    {
        // Normalize the title
        $slug = str_slug($title);
        // Get any that could possibly be related.
        // This cuts the queries down by doing it once.
        $allSlugs = $this->getRelatedSlugs($slug, $id);
        // If we haven't used it before then we are all good.
        if (!$allSlugs->contains('slug', $slug)) {
            return $slug;
        }
        // Just append numbers like a savage until we find not used.
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) {
            $newSlug = $slug . '-' . $i;
            if (!$allSlugs->contains('slug', $newSlug)) {
                return $newSlug;
            }
        }
        throw new \Exception('Can not create a unique slug');
    }

    protected function getRelatedSlugs($slug, $id = 0)
    {
        return Model::select('slug')->where('slug', 'like', $slug . '%')
            ->where('id', '<>', $id)
            ->get();
    }
}
```

Comment: well i thought about what u say before i select another answer, but right now that could be the answer to fix my solution for now, but i always thought about what u said, and i was looking for a example to get rid of random str too, but thanks, i guess this is better way for me, for now.

Answer (score 1):

You could use inbuilt `Str` class, and create some random strings in your `Post` slug. Example:

```
static::creating(function ($course){
        $course->slug = str_slug($course->name . Str::random( 2 ));
    });
```

This will add 2 random strings on each slug you create, which will ensure there are no duplicates. You can find more about `Str` class [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-str-random).

Answer (score 0):

you can use laravel Inbuilt Helper, follow below link.

```
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-str-slug
 $data = 'My Data'
$slug = Str::slug($data, '-');
dd($slug);
```

add this in your controller

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
```